# how to create custom cordova plugin using javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

Is it possible creating cordova plugin using JavaScript and without Java code.
Plugin preferable for Android.

If yes, please tell me how?

Comment: Nop you will have to link javascript to native source that is called plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, you should use Java code to create plugin and integrate it using javascript.

An example for creating cordova plugin in Java and calling it in javascript

http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-how-to-write-a-phonegap-plugin-for-android/